# FormFlow Remove a specific field from status message

Tags: c#, botframework

Is there a way in FormFlow to have certain fields presented to the user as questions but not visible when the user type **status** or when we use the {*} symbol?
This is maybe similar to how Confirm() and Message() are behaving.